# What does "some fifty in all" mean?

Tags: numbers

From the book [Packing for Mars](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/08/09/books/excerpt-packing-for-mars.html):

> This is the building with the mock-ups, **some fifty in all** — modules, airlocks, hatches, capsules.

What does *some [number] in all* mean? Does it mean there are fifty **kinds of mockups**, or there are fifty **mockups**, that each kind might have several of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a way of saying the estimated total is around fifty (i.e. 50 + or -  a few).  Rewritten....

> This is the building with the mock-ups, about fifty total -- modules, airlocks, hatches, capsules.

Comment: Just to be clear, does it mean there are fifty **kinds of mockups**, or there are fifty **mockups**, that each kind might have several of them?

Comment: It means there are fifty total mock-ups, composed of modules, airlocks, etc.

Comment: Oh, so each mockup can be a (unique) combination of those parts?

Comment: @Ooker No, that's not implied.  The list after the dash (--) presents examples.  Based on the sentence I would assume that a mock-up is an actual module, airlock, hatch, or capsule.  These items are mocked-up.  The sentence doesn't imply that combinations of those items are also mock-ups.